# crontab doesn't run vino-server

Tags: cron, vino

i'm trying to run vino-server from crontab:

```
* * * * * /home/nvidia/run_vino.sh > /home/nvidia/LOG 2>&1
```

using this script:

```
#! /bin/bash

export DISPLAY=:0.0
xhost +
nohup /usr/lib/vino/vino-server --display=:0.0
```

but server doesn't start and i get next messages in /home/nvidia/LOG:

```
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host

(vino-server:21503): dconf-CRITICAL **: 20:51:02.009: unable to create file '/home/nvidia/.cache/dconf/user': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.

(vino-server:21503): dconf-CRITICAL **: 20:51:05.041: unable to create file '/home/nvidia/.cache/dconf/user': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
** Message: 20:51:05.045: The desktop sharing service is already running, exiting.
```

what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify a user for the cron job. Assuming you can run the script yourself from the command line then add your user name in the 6th position in the cron tab entry for your job. That’s between the last * and the command to run the job.